# Do I have to patch PrivateTunnel OpenVPN so that certificates are validated?

Tags: release-freya, openvpn

I use Private Tunnel VPN. The [support website](https://www.privatetunnel.com/home/support/) (under Connection questions: How do I connect to PrivateTunnel using Ubuntu Linux?) recommends this for Ubuntu :

> ### Configuring Network Manager to Validate Server Certificates
>
> Since the
>   default configuration cannot validate server certificates properly, it
>   is possible for someone to impersonate as PrivateTunnel and compromise
>   your data integrity. For this reason, it is strongly recommended that
>   you apply the patch below so that server certificates are validated
>   prior to a successful connection. To do this, copy and paste the
>   command below into a Terminal window (this patch will have to be
>   reapplied if you upgrade your operating system or if the plugin is
>   upgraded to a new version):

```
mv /usr/sbin/openvpn /usr/local/sbin; echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n/usr/local/sbin/openvpn $* --ns-cert-type server &\ntrap "kill $!" EXIT\nwait $!\n' > /usr/sbin/openvpn; chmod +x /usr/sbin/openvpn
```

Will i need to do this in elementary OS Freya?

Comment: This is not really a question we can answer, you should rather ask Private Tunnel support. In my personal opinion, as elementary is basically Ubuntu under the hood, their recommendation should apply to elementary too. (That does not mean I think their recommendation is good / bad or that you should / should not do it.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your question is more of a "Does this indication apply to my system, elementary OS?" with a follow up of "Is it really necessary?", with that in mind:

## Does this indication apply to my system, elementary OS?

Private tunnel uses openvpn for their connection, elementary OS does not ship a modified version of openvpn. `apt-cache policy` allows you to see the version and source of a package.

```
apt-cache policy network-manager-openvpn openvpn
network-manager-openvpn:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.9.8.2-1ubuntu4
  Version table:
     0.9.8.2-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
openvpn:
  Installed: 2.3.2-7ubuntu3.1
  Candidate: 2.3.2-7ubuntu3.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.3.2-7ubuntu3.1 0
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.3.2-7ubuntu3 0
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Based on that, any recommendations for openvpn in Ubuntu 14.04 apply to elementaryOS.

## Is it really necessary?

The website does not specify a concrete version of Ubuntu, although it should not cripple your installation of openvpn, you should ask them (support@privatetunnel.com) if these indications still apply to `Ubuntu 14.04` (base of elementary OS) before following their directions.